# I want to display table field ExpNo in TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I want to display `table field ExpNo` in `TextView,` Please help me to write query in cursor or which way that you know...

Sql Query is like : `Select Max(ExpNo) from table;`
(how to write this query in android)

please help me...

i was write like :

```
public void dispExpNo()  
   {
    String[] exno = {"ExpNo"};  
    Cursor c = db.query("tb_expense",exno,null,null,null,null,null);                
    txtExpno.setText(""+c.getInt(0));
    c.close();          
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a rawQuery if you want like this:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select Max(ExpNo) from table", null);
txtExpno.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ExpNo")));
```

or you can use the standard android query also like this:

```
Cursor c=db.query("tb_expense",exno,"MAX(ExpNo)",null,null,null,null);
txtExpno.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ExpNo")));
```